# How does zlib works with Z_FIXED strategy?

Tags: compression, zlib

A quick look at the documentation states that :

```
Z_FIXED prevents the use of dynamic Huffman codes, 
allowing for a simpler decoder for special applications.
```

So, if it does not use dynamic Huffman, what does it uses instead ? A static table ?

If so, where is it defined ?
Can it be defined and loaded by the user ? (or hacked into the code ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixed tables are defined in the [deflate format specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I read this RFC so many times in the past that I was sure to know it almost by heart. I somehow manage to forget 3.2.6. Compression with fixed Huffman codes (BTYPE=01). The question somehow still holds : is Z_FIXED forcing this mode ?

Comment: Yes.  (SO won't let me answer just "Yes.", so I added this superfluous sentence.)